# Trying to use Javascript regex to grab a section of "&" delimited text whether or not it's the last value

Tags: javascript, regex

My text looks similar to this:

```
action=addItem&siteId=4&lang_locale=en_US&country=US&catalogId=1&productId=417689&displaySize=7&skuSize=2194171&qty=1&pil=7&psh=had+AIRJRnjbp7+rGivIKg00
```

and I want to replace the value of 'psh'.  It may sometimes not be the last value (it may be followed by `&something=else`).

I've tried doing these lines of code:

1. `var text = text.replace(/&psh=.*(?=&|$)/, "&psh=" + data.psh);`
2. `var text = text.replace(/&psh=.*(?=[&|$]+)/, "&psh=" + data.psh);`
3. `var text = text.replace(/(?:&psh=)(.*)(?=[&|$]+)/, data.psh);`

None of them work for both situations.  Use [this site](http://regexpal.com/) to check regexes.

Comment: Could help others: http://jsfiddle.net/2kfHv/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
var text = text.replace(/&psh=[^&]*/, "&psh=" + data.psh);
```

`[^&]*` matches a string of any length that consists of any characters except `&`, therefore the match will continue until the end of the string or until (but not including) the next `&`, whichever comes first.

Comment: That worked beautifully. It makes sense that I didn't want to look for everything (`.*`), just stuff that isn't an ampersand.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer may work, but I fear it is not the best possible answer.  The string you are giving as an example looks a lot like a url.  If it is, that means there can sometimes be a pound sign in it as well (#).  To compensate for that you actually need to modify your code to look like this:

```
var text = text.replace(/&psh=[^&#]*/, "&psh=" + data.psh);
```

Notice the # which was added in order to not get tripped up by anchor tags in the url.